# YAML-cpp null string parsing?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-parsing, yaml-cpp

How do I get this code to parse `""` as a string (or recognize it is not an acceptable string)? I am using [this YAML-cpp library](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) which I verified treats this as a `NodeType::value()` and not a `NodeType::Null`.

```
std::string getFilepath() {
    YAML::Node nodeValue = node["filepath"];
    if(nodeValue.Type() == YAML::NodeType::value()){
        return nodeValue.as<std::string>(); //Breaks here
    }
    return "";
}
```

In the .yaml file, the entry is listed as `filepath: ""`

`YAML::NodeType`does not include more specific variable types than `value()` and `Null`.

Here's the specific error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::string>'
what():  bad conversion
```

The only work-around I have figured out so far is a try-catch block.

Comment: It should be ok with that as a string. Can you post your entire YAML file and a complete minimal parsing example?

Comment: The entire YAML file is far too big, and that really is the whole of it. I can post a link to the YAML-cpp library I am using though.

Comment: Can you find a minimal example that exhibits the same behavior?